# Affinity Designer: how to clean up compound path

Tags: logo, shapes, path, affinity-designer

I don't really know how to describe this problem, but I just want a clean cut if you know what I mean. It seems like the ellipse is trying to form an ellipse again and so there are new lines in the middle, how can I get rid of the lines in the middle? Adobe Illustrator does the same thing.

[image: I want to cut the rectangle out of the circle]
[image: It leaves lines in the middle which I don't want]

Comment: That is perfectly normal strokes need to be expanded for them to react to operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you’re after is possible. There’s two approaches I can think of that work.

#### Destructive

If you are happy with a destructive approach, expanding the stoke prior to the boolean operation will give you want you’re after. To do this select the ellipse layer and choose `Layer` → `Expand Stroke`.

#### Non-destructive

If you’d like to maintain the ability to edit the stroke width, you’ll likely have to use some of Affinity Designer’s masking abilities. I’ve masked the circle with a compound path of two rectangles.

[image: Affinity Designer masking]

To do this, drag the layer you’d like *to be masked* to the layer you’d like to *mask it with*. Drag to the area just to the right of the layer thumbnail.

[image: Drag to make a mask in Affinity Designer]

Given it’s for a logo, using a destructive method is probably best for the final assets.

Comment: @Tanonic Not a problem at all. :D

Comment: With the newer versions of Affinity Designer, the Boolean Operations tools (Illustrator Pathfinder equivalent) allow a non-destructive workflow by holding Alt (Opt Mac) when clicking on the crop (or other operation) figure - this automatically creates a compound path which is saved in your layers studio - so that you can easily live-edit your boolean later.

Answer (score 0):

Break the residues of the ellipse at the corners. Then delete the straight parts. You have the "Break Curve" tool in the context menu when you use the "Node" tool.

This leaves the ends as usual open curve ends. Should they be along the cutting line (=horizontal) - then this method does not work.